# Ignore missing array objects from JSON in Dataweave

Tags: json, null, mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am using Anypoint Studio 6.1 and Mule 3.8.1 and am mapping JSON to JSON in Dataweave.  In the JSON mapping I have an optional field called "Channels" which contains a list of strings.  When the field is not there I get a warning in Dataweave.  How can I write the Dataweave code to ignore if its null?

**Dataweave code:**

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
payload map ((payload01 , indexOfPayload01) -> {
    Channels: payload01.Channels map ((channel , indexOfAccessChannel) -> channel)
})
```

I have tried to use "when" and also the "?" selector modifier but cannot get the syntax right.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were right to use `when` and the `?` operator. You just need to use parentheses to make sure they apply to the right things.  Note that I am using `$` as a shorthand for the `payload01` parameter in your example.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json

---
payload map {
    (Channels: $.Channels map (lower $)) when $.Channels?
}
```

If you didn't need to use `map` on the `Channels` array within each item, you could just allow the `null` to pass through:

```
payload map {
    Channels: $.Channels
}
```

This would yield the following for input objects that don't contain a `Channels` field:

```
{
    Channels: null
}
```

Adding the parentheses allows us to use `when` to determine whether the whole key/value pair (aka tuple) should be output:

```
payload map {
    (Channels: $.Channels) when $.Channels?
}
```

Yielding:

```
{
}
```